# Python Django change value based on selectbox index changed

Tags: python, django

I have a table that fetches data from a python django database the first column is a select box with products names i want the value of price column to change based on product selection how do i achieve that

```
<table>
 {% for item in items %}
   <tr>


 <select name="sel0" id="selectbox" onchange="">
            {% for product in products  %}
            <option value="{{ product.id }}" id="optionval">{{product.name}}</option>                              
            {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <td>price</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Total</td>
   </tr>
  {% endfor%}


</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it, is write ajax call on change event of product list.
On load price of default selected product should be displayed.
On Product change retrieve price from database and update respective price value in frontend.

```
    $(document).on('change', '#selectbox', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Urls['url_to_view']({{ product.id }}),
        data:{
             csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
        },
        success: function(response){
            price = response.price
            // code to change price in front end
        }
    })
});
```